# How to use token generated by knox in api view function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using knox and not rest_framework.authtoken. I am also able to generate tokens right now but I am having issue in using it. According to the documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/), an api function view requires

```
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
```

I replace Session and Basic to TokenAuthentication but I am getting the error of `NameError: name 'authentication_classes' is not defined`

In my views according to the documentation, i have imported the following:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
```

Updated:

Tokens are generated upon register/login in Postman and I used the Token:
[image]

In the views:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def device_list(request):
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    deviceserializer = DeviceSerializers(devices, many = True)
    return Response(deviceserializer.data)
```

I am using https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-register-login-logout as a guide on how to generate the key and then using it in one of my api view but it can't seem to work. Am I using it wrongly?

Here is the traceback when i tried to send in the Get request with the token

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 414, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "c:\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 78, in wrap_attributeerrors
    raise exc.with_traceback(info[2])
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 74, in wrap_attributeerrors
    yield
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\authentication.py", line 196, in authenticate
    return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
  File "C:\Users\P1338475\.virtualenvs\django_swing-t91g66f4\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\authentication.py", line 202, in authenticate_credentials
    except model.DoesNotExist:
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'
```

Comment: It seems you removed `from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes` as well?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didnt saw that in the page i looked at. But now I am having a issue when I attempt to use it. Can help me take a look and point to me what is wrong? I am quite new on using this

Comment: Ok in that case if you are using [knox](https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/auth/), shouldn't you use `from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication` and not `from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication`

Comment: Thank you very much ! It finally worked. I thought using rest_framework still works as within the settings.py under installed apps, it is still using ```rest_framework```